# Cannot make an SQL query work from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm trying to run a very simple PHP function :

```
function evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$id,$e,$p){
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id={$id} AND email= '$e' AND password= '$p' AND activated=1 LIMIT 1 ";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        echo $sql;
    }
}
```

as part of a  user authentication. The problem is that the query is not working and I dont know why! I know the mysql connection is working as I have checked the mysqli_errno and not getting anything there - Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the database is returning errors after you run your query, as well as after making the connection?

Comment: try `$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($db_conx));`

Comment: try executing the query within your DBMS. Does it return a result?

Comment: hi Fabio - just tried this and now my output is not executing the "echo $sql" but I am also not getting $numrows either

Comment: What part is not working?

Comment: @stefanoL - I've tried that and its not returning but I'm not sure why - it just says 'Loading' and nothing is happeneing - The strange thing is that I'm using almost exactly the same query on the same DB in other PHP pages and its working fine

Comment: @ibu I'm not getting a row ie I'm getting !$numrows, although I know that it's there for the arguments passed

Comment: investigate whether one of your columns has the wrong data type in relation to your value<->value comparison in the query.. hard to explain lol

Comment: @stefano - I understand what you mean but that's all ok as I can run almost extactly the same query on the same table from another php page which is what makes it wierd

Comment: and wheres the difference in the queries? Does the other "almost exactly" query work within your DBMS?

Comment: the only difference is that the other one is selecting * while this one is selecting only ip

Comment: Well you know it has something to do with your db data / column names/ aliases when even your dbms returns no result.

Comment: Try LIMIT 0, 1 instead of LIMIT 1

Comment: stefano - the other one is working with the DBMS - i think it might be to do with the database connection include

Comment: The primary error cannot be the php code when the query doesn't work within your dbms!

Comment: the only thing I can think of in that case is that the id is an integer, but when run through the $sql it becomes a VARCHAR/string? if so how can i avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
function evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$id,$e,$p){
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND email= '$e' AND password= '$p' AND activated=1 LIMIT 1 ";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        echo $sql;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ramesh - am getting the same problem - the string that I get for the query looks correct, but its still not getting the entry (its just echoing $sql again

Comment: which version of Mysql are you using, cause mysqli_X works only with mysql5+ ( i guess). if version is issue then you can give a try for 
`mysql_query($sql,$db_conx)`;

Comment: @Mobaz .. if answer is helpful then, give your feedback or accept as answer or mark as helpful answer ;), it will help other it identify find their related answers

Comment: Hi Ramesh - no worries - thanks for the input, though I had already tried this - it turns out the problem was not in any of these issues which are all correct but in my include command for my $db_conx variable

Answer (score -1):

Values gets substituted by default inside double quotes. But make sure you check the connection too.

```
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id=$id AND email= $e AND password= $p AND activated=1 LIMIT 1 ";
```

Comment: but the $e ad $p variables contain strange characters i.e. @ and $ so need to go into single quotation marks no?